# Google drive v3 C# sdk ResumableUpload One or more errors occurred

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

When I upload a 10-15mb .mov file I get the following exception:

```
One or more errors occurred.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.Upload()
```

But if I upload a smaller 100-200kb .jpg file it is fine.

Upload part of the code:

```
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;

try
{
    using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath,
            System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        request = service.Files.Create(
            fileMetadata, stream, fileMetadata.MimeType);
        request.Fields = "id";
        request.Upload();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it, or be able to get more error details.

Thanks

Comment: Did you go over the [Performing a Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload)?

Comment: I thought the .net library used ResumableUpload?

If you look at the error message it seems to be calling ResumableUpload